# Tenant/Landlord - Not locking the front door violate tenant's right to a livable place? (California)

Tags: residential-lease, landlord, tenant, breaking-the-lease

For Housing, between tenant and landlord in California:
Does not locking the front door on a regular basis count as a violation of the tenant's right to a livable (safe and habitable) place?
If so, what methods of recourse does the tenant and landlord have?
Can the tenant break their lease due to this reason?

The front door has working lock and deadbolt.
Tenant is free to get a lock on their own bedroom door. They are paying for just their bedroom, and "access" to common areas.

Comment: Is the landlord living on the premises? If so, it’s likely you are a boarder not a tenant - usually different right apply.

Comment: Did/will the landlord provide a lock for the tenant/boarder's individual room?

Comment: @DaleM yes, on premise. Hmm ok thank you for that

Comment: @Damila no. not provided.